# How can I differentiate in redux reducers between different instance variables coming from a single action in rails backend-api controller

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, reactjs, redux

Ok, so I have an action inside of my possible_matches controller called setup_possible_matches which renders json.

```
def setup_possible_matches
   @contemplated_piece = @visible_gor_clothing || GorClothing.where(gender: :male).order(created_at: :desc).first
   @standalone_bottoms = GorClothing.where('standalone = ?', true).where('merch_type = ?', 'bottom').where.not('id = ?', @contemplated_piece).where(gender: :male).order(created_at: :desc)
   @standalone_tops = GorClothing.where('standalone = ?', true).where('merch_type = ?', 'top').where.not('id = ?', @contemplated_piece).where(gender: :male).order(created_at: :desc)
   @suggested_tops = GorClothing.joins(:toggled_pieces).where('merch_type = ?', 'top').where('possible_matches.contemplated_piece_id = ?', @contemplated_piece.id).where(gender: :male).order(created_at: :desc)
   @suggested_bottoms = GorClothing.joins(:toggled_pieces).where('merch_type = ?', 'bottom').where('possible_matches.contemplated_piece_id = ?', @contemplated_piece.id).where(gender: :male).order(created_at: :desc)
   @extra_tops = GorClothing.joins(:toggled_pieces).where('merch_type = ?', 'top').where.not('possible_matches.contemplated_piece_id = ?', @contemplated_piece.id).where('standalone = ?', false).where(gender: :male).order(created_at: :desc)
   @extra_bottoms = GorClothing.joins(:toggled_pieces).where('merch_type = ?', 'bottom').where.not('possible_matches.contemplated_piece_id = ?', @contemplated_piece.id).where('standalone = ?', false).where(gender: :male).order(created_at: :desc)
   render json: {contemplated_piece: @contemplated_piece, standalone_tops: @standalone_tops, standalone_bottoms: @standalone_bottoms, suggested_tops: @suggested_tops, suggested_bottoms: @suggested_bottoms, extra_tops: @extra_tops, extra_bottoms: @extra_bottoms}
end
```

Inside of db/seeds.rb, I seeded the GorClothing database with:

```
GorClothing.create(merch_type: 'top', description: 'Perfect for a night out with the boys', gender: 'male', sizes: 'M', colors_available: 'Gray', price: '$59.99', standalone: true, quantity: 5, images_attributes: [{type_of_image: 1, picture: File.open(File.join(Rails.root, 'app/assets/images/CoolNightClubShirt.png'))}])

GorClothing.create(merch_type: 'top', description: 'Bon Vivant', gender: 'male', sizes: 'M', colors_available: 'black', price: '$64.99', standalone: true, quantity: 6, images_attributes: [{type_of_image: 1, picture: File.open(File.join(Rails.root, 'app/assets/images/CoolPartyHostShirt.png'))}])

GorClothing.create(merch_type: 'top', description: 'At the beach bar ordering martinis; Learning how to salsa dance; This piece simply communicates that we are unbothered with the things that might weigh down others', gender: 'male', sizes: 'M', colors_available: 'black', price: '$64.99', standalone: true, quantity: 6, images_attributes: [{type_of_image: 1, picture: File.open(File.join(Rails.root, 'app/assets/images/CoolWhiteShirt.png'))}])

GorClothing.create(merch_type: 'top', description: 'To a baseball game, to a concert, to a get-together, this has casual written all over it.', gender: 'male', sizes: 'M', colors_available: 'black', price: '$64.99', standalone: true, quantity: 6, images_attributes: [{type_of_image: 1, picture: File.open(File.join(Rails.root, 'app/assets/images/DopeCasualShirt.png'))}])

GorClothing.create(merch_type: 'top', description: 'Honored guest much?', gender: 'male', sizes: 'M', colors_available: 'Gray', price: '$49.99', standalone: true, quantity: 4, images_attributes: [{type_of_image: 1, picture: File.open(File.join(Rails.root, 'app/assets/images/CoolWineTastingShirt.png'))}])

GorClothing.create(merch_type: 'top', description: 'Too Fresh. Like Fresh Prince of Bel-Air Fresh. Okay, lemme stop.', gender: 'male', sizes: 'M', colors_available: 'White', price: '$39.99', standalone: true, quantity: 4, images_attributes: [{type_of_image: 1, picture: File.open(File.join(Rails.root, 'app/assets/images/FunkyTropicalShirt.png'))}])
```

Inside of the views/possible_matches/setup_possible_matches.json.builder file, I have:

```
json.contemplated_piece @contemplated_piece :standalone, :merch_type, :gender, :price, :created_at
json.standalone_bottoms @standalone_bottoms :merch_type, :gender, :price, :created_at
json.standalone_tops @standalone_tops :standalone, :merch_type, :gender, :price, :created_at
hash = {:toggled_pieces => {:contemplated_piece_id => @contemplated_piece.id}}
json.suggested_tops @suggested_tops :merch_type, :gender, :created_at, :price json.merge hash
hash - {:toggled_pieces => {:contemplated_piece_id => @contemplated_piece.id}}
json.suggested_bottoms @suggested_bottoms :merch_type, :price, :gender, :created_at, json.merge hash
json.extra_tops @extra_tops :merch_type, :standalone, :gender, :price, :created_at                  
json.extra_bottoms @extra_bottoms :merch_type, :standalone, :price, :gender, :created_at
```

The action is called upon by a redux action inside of the actions/index.js file.

```
export function defaultPieces(){
    return function(dispatch){
        fetch(`${API_URL}/possible_matches/setup_possible_matches`, {
            headers: {
                'Accept': 'application/json',
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            }
        }).then((res) => res.json())
        .then((json) => {
            dispatch(getInitialPieces(json))        
        })
    }
}
export function getInitialPieces(request){
    return {
        type: INITIAL_PIECES,
        payload: request
    }
}
```

I am trying to get the mapStateToProps method to understand the difference between the different instance variables that are defined in any particular action inside of the possibleMatches controller from the rails backend api namely setup_possible_matches above.

```
function mapStateToProps(state){
    return {
        UpperComponents: state.possibleMatches.UpperComponents,
        LowerComponents: state.possibleMatches.LowerComponents,
        contemplatedPiece: state.possibleMatches.contemplated_piece,
        extraTops: state.possibleMatches.extraTops,
        extraBottoms: state.possibleMatches.extraBottoms,
        standaloneTops: state.possibleMatches.standaloneTops,
        standaloneBottoms: state.possibleMatches.standaloneBottoms,
        suggestedTops: state.possibleMatches.suggestedTops,
        suggestedBottoms: state.possibleMatches.suggestedBottoms
    };
}
```

Inside of reducers/index.js, we have:

```
const allReducers = combineReducers({
       possibleMatches: PossibleMatchesReducer,
       routing: routerReducer,
       form: formReducer
});
```

In the console, I get an error:

Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'contemplated_piece' of undefined

It refers to a line inside of the PossibleMatches reducer:

```
case INITIAL_PIECES:
    console.log('Initial_Pieces: ', action.payload);
    return Object.assign({}, state, {contemplated_piece: action.payload.data.contemplated_piece}, <-- this line
                                    {extraTops: action.payload.data.extra_tops},
                                    {extraBottoms: action.payload.data.extra_bottoms},
                                    {standaloneTops: action.payload.data.standalone_tops},
                                    {standaloneBottoms: action.payload.data.standalone_bottoms},
                                    {suggestedTops: action.payload.data.suggested_tops},
                                    {suggestedBottoms: action.payload.data.suggested_bottoms})
```

Inside of the console, this is what gets returned relative to the console.log(action.payload) line above:

[image]

In the console, we also get TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined

Inside of the PossibleMatches controller, we have:

```
class PossibleMatches extends Component{
constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.props.defaultPieces().then(function(results){console.log('Results: ', results)});
}

...rest of Component

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
 return {
    defaultPieces: () => {
      dispatch(defaultPieces())
    }
  }
}
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(PossibleMatches)
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Please provide the code where `PossibleMatchesReducer ` called.
It would be hepful if you add debug info in this reducer `console.log(action.payload)`. I assume there is no data.

Comment: And also as I see default pieces function returns nothing.
Try to return promise

Comment: Im a little confused as to what you're talking about when you say provide the code where PossibleMatchesReducer is called. That's up above. defaultPieces calls getInitialPieces and getInitialPieces returns a type: INITIAL_PIECES, so the case INITIAL_PIECES inside the PossibleMatches reducer corresponds with that. I will update the question above with the console.log statements within the reducer.

Comment: Rails should not give such structure.
Can you do debugging `console.log(json)` where above `dispatch(getInitialPieces(json)) ` call?

Comment: It returns the same thing the console.log(action.payload) statement returns. What do you mean by 'Rails should not give such structure'?

Comment: I mean there should be json object in response and you have an array of arrays, according to `console.log`

Comment: So I have a jbuilder file that I'll post up above to show that the json I'm trying to render has been formatted a certain way.

Answer (score 0):

So, it turns out that I had a silly before_action filter inside of the rails controller that was prompted another method being called first which did render json but with two arrays inside of a hash. That's why I was getting the results I was getting in the console (what I posted up above). I simply needed to get that out of the picture and the correct data was returned.